# Is it possible to package two UWP Apps using Windows Application Packging Project?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I have two UWP projects, one for a Custom Share UI, which is a ShareTarget App, and a main Application, both are uwp.

And, I have the following app structure.  (All the sample apps in this case, all created from the 'new project' and basically do not have any content in them, except for the default content)

[image]

But, when I build the WapProjTemplate1 I get the following error logs,

***Error    APPX1101    Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'App.xbf'. Source files: 
\source\repos\WapProjTemplate1\App1\bin\x64\Debug\App.xbf
source\repos\WapProjTemplate1\App2\bin\x64\Debug\App.xbf    WapProjTemplate1    D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets    1766***

Is it even possible to have two apps?

The reason I want two apps is because, I want to invoke the main app from the ShareUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have two separate apps for enabling Sharing.  Your main app will just declare itself as the receptor of Sharing in its manifest [as per docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-to-app/receive-data).

It will then launch (if it's not running) or get re-activated if it is, with the following `OnShareTargetActivated` event;

```
protected override async void OnShareTargetActivated(ShareTargetActivatedEventArgs args)
```

Here is where you can redirect to a different page, or pop open a new window populated with the data from the share.

Comment: thanks for responding. But can you tell me if it is possible to do that ? I'll tell you the reason why I want that, when my main app is running and I click on Share from edge, OnShareTargetActivated gets called and we navigate to a share page but when we close that share page , the main app stops responding (after we minimize and later maximize the app) I hear that I has to do with different window having different thread issue and we are not tracking the dispatchers

Comment: please help with my question @Michael Hawker - MSFT

Comment: According to [this article](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/wep-documentation/msix/applications-in-msix-packages/) it's possible but not to upload to store. I'm not an expert on packaging though.

The proper way is a single app with the share target event. It sounds like there's some threading/windowing things you need to work out.  Be sure to look at this sample for more help: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/MultipleViews

The new AppWindow API may be useful too: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/AppWindow